# Compiler optimization of method calls

Tags: java, performance, compiler-optimization

Does the Java compiler apply some transformations to optimize method calls? Or does it always generate a faithful representation of the source with simple optimizations like removing dead code?

Specifically if we have the below example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(foo());
    System.out.println(foo());
    System.out.println(foo());
    System.out.println(bar());
    System.out.println(bar());
    System.out.println(bar());
}

public static int foo() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return arr[0];
}

public static int bar() {
    return 10;
}
```

Does the compiler attempt to replace the call to `bar` (or even possibly `foo`) with a call to print the integer `10`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(1);
    System.out.println(1);
    System.out.println(1);
    System.out.println(10);
    System.out.println(10);
    System.out.println(10);
}
```

I know of a method called **inlining** that can lead to such transformations, but I was wondering if the Java compiler (at least the `javac` of the Oracle JDK) applies it, or if it's always deferred to the JVM.

Comment: The answer is 'it depends'. Java has a [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), as well as doing some manner of optimizations when turning the source into byte-code. So basically, as long as it doesn't change the observable behavior of the code, Java can really do any kind of optimization at any time.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096361/are-there-inline-functions-in-java

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256202/how-does-the-java-jit-compiler-optimize-my-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of optimization is called [*constant folding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

These (and other optimizations) that do not affect the observable result of programs are allowed by Java's specification.

However, whether or not a given compiler actually performs these optimizations is entirely up to the implementation.